# How to handle user inputed data that might be the same for multiple users

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-modeling

If I was to create a marketplace database for something specific, lets say for books. I would have a `store` table and a `store_books` table that would contain the books of each store.

Now if there is a high probability of multiple stores selling the exact same book would it be a good idea to keep another table `books` containing book related information and put prices etc in the `store_book` table? I also want to add languages using another two tables `book_langs` and `langs`.

Where in `book_langs` I have the localized information and `langs` contains all supported languages.

My main concern in this case is that if a store needs to add a new book it will create the first entry in the `books` table as well as all the translations which will be the ones used by everyone. If someone translates wrong, misspells or if there simply is multiple ways of translating lets say a title this would introduce a mess in the database since everyone will start creating new entries for each book. What would be a good approach of solving such kind of problems? De-normalizing the `store_books` to contain the title would be one approach but is that preferred approach?

Please take the books as an example. One could argue that a book needs to have a specific title since it was translated. Think of the book as a placeholder since I can't think of a better example at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between "editions" of the same book.  I would argue that translations are different *editions* and stored sell *editions*.  In your case, an "edition" could simply be a book/language combination.  So, call it `BookLanguageId`.

Something like the following entities:

```
create table Books (
     BookId b int auto_increment primary key,
     Title varchar(255),
     . . .
);

create table BookLanguages (
    BookLanguageId int auto_increment primary key,
    BookId int not null,
    LanguageId int not null,
    IsPrimaryLanguage tinyint,
    . . . 
    foreign key (BookId) references Books(BookId),
    foreign key (LanguageId) references Languages(LanguageId)
);


create table StoreBookLanguages (
    StoreBookLanguageId int auto_increment primary key,
    StoreId not null,
    BookLanguageId int not null,
    DateArrived int,
    foreign key (StoreId) references Stores(StoreId),
    foreign key (BookLanguageId) references BookLanguages(BookLanguageId)
);
```